# Correct way to save/serialize custom objects in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom object, a `UIImageView` subclass which has a few `gestureRecognizer` objects.

If I have a number of these objects stored in a `NSMutableArray`, how would this array of objects be saved to disk so that it can be loaded when the user runs the app again?

I would like to load the array from the disk and use the objects.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

My implementation for something similar is the following and works perfectly :

The custom object (Settings) should implement the protocol NSCoding :

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.difficulty forKey:@"difficulty"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.language forKey:@"language"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.category forKey:@"category"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.playerType forKey:@"playerType"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.difficulty = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"difficulty"];
        self.language = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"language"];
        self.category = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"category"];
        self.playerType = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"playerType"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The following code writes the custom object to a file (set.txt) and then restores it to the array myArray :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"set.txt"];

NSMutableArray *myObject=[NSMutableArray array];
[myObject addObject:self.settings];    

[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myObject toFile:appFile]; 

NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:appFile];
```

Comment: This should have more votes. Complete solution and really helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: For as long as your custom object complies to `NSCoding` and implements `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`, you can use it as the root object upon archiving. No need to put it in an `NSMutableArray` as in this code.

Comment: FYI: Take a look at this http://nshipster.com/nscoding/ if you want more information on how's, when's and why's of NSKeyedArchiver and NSCoding.

Comment: Make sure if you are encoding and decoding items like NSUIntegers to handle the NSCoding like this:  
     self.versionNum = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"versionNum"] unsignedIntegerValue]; 
and
     [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:self.versionNum] forKey:@"versionNum"];

Comment: Should `if (self = [super init])` be `if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])`?

Comment: Yes, if the custom class has another super custom class. @MatthewCawley

Answer (score 35):

```
//store the array
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:@"someFile"];

//load the array
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"someFile"];
```

[Official References](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

Note that when the array contains custom object types, you must ensure your type conforms to the [NSCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) before this will work.

Comment: Thanks. So this should return the array as it was when saved, no matter what is in the array? Will the array items be retrievable and usable?

Comment: I may just be doing it wrong but I don't think code this simple works for custom objects, both methods are returning 'No'.

Comment: @Deco - Custom object types must confirm to the [NSCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

This blog post explains how to store an array of custom objects to disk using [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and read it back with [NSKeyedUnarchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/240775-saving-nsarray-of-custom-objects.html

Apple also has a very helpful guide on the matter, the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my improvements to Kostas solution, if somebody needs them.

1. A class name can be used to generate text file name to store object.
2. It is a good solution to save objects of a view controller in viewWillDisappear method and restore them in viewDidLoad method.
3. File name should be generated in separate method to avoid duplicate code.
4. After restoring object, it should be checked to be not nil.

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Restoring form object from the file
  NSString *formFilePath = [self formFilePath];
  RRCreateResumeForm *form = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:formFilePath];
  if (form != nil) {
    self.formController.form = form;
  }
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  // Saving the form object to the file
  NSString *formFilePath = [self formFilePath];
  [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.formController.form toFile:formFilePath];
}


// Returns a file path to the file with stored form data for form controller
- (NSString *)formFilePath
{
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *formClassName = NSStringFromClass( [self.formController.form class] );
  NSString *formFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt", formClassName];
  NSString *formFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:formFileName];

  return formFilePath;
}
```