# iOS: how to serialize a non-NSCoding compliant object

Tags: ios, serialization, nscoding

I already take a look around and found the closes answer here:

> [Correct way to save/serialize custom objects in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413851/correct-way-to-save-serialize-custom-objects-in-ios)

But this is only applicable for custom objects that is user-created. My problem is serializing "SKProduct" which is a derived class that is non-NSCoding compliant. Specifically, the exact error I encountered:

```
-[SKProduct encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4027160
```

Does anyone have similar experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface this answer by saying **there's probably an easier way**; but class substitution during archiving and unarchiving is one approach you could take.

During archiving, you have the option of setting a delegate that conforms to the `NSKeyedArchiverDelegate` protocol.  All of the methods are optional.  The delegate receives a message `archiver:willEncodeObject:` message during encoding.  If you wish to substitute a class during archiving, you can create a substitute object and return it.  Otherwise just return the original object.

In your case, you could create a 'shadow object' for `SKProduct` that encapsulates whatever properties on the original class you are interested in serializing.  Then substitute that class during archiving.  During unarchiving, you could reverse the process and return `SKProduct`

For illustrative purposes, here's an example.  Mind you, I've left out the reverse substitution part - but if you read the docs on `NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate` I think it would be clear.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NoncompliantClass:NSObject
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger foo;
@end

@implementation NoncompliantClass
@synthesize foo = _foo;
@end

@interface CompliantClass:NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger foo;
@end

@implementation CompliantClass
@synthesize foo = _foo;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeInteger:self.foo forKey:@"FooKey"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) { return nil; }

    _foo = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"FooKey"];
    return self;
}

@end

@interface ArchiverDelegate:NSObject <NSKeyedArchiverDelegate>
@end

@implementation ArchiverDelegate
- (id)archiver:(NSKeyedArchiver *)archiver willEncodeObject:(id)object {
    NSString *objClassName = NSStringFromClass([object class]);
    NSLog(@"Encoding %@",objClassName);
    if( [object isMemberOfClass:[NoncompliantClass class]] ) {
        NSLog(@"Substituting");
        CompliantClass *replacementObj = [CompliantClass new];
        replacementObj.foo = [object foo];
        return replacementObj;
    }
    return object;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NoncompliantClass *cat1 = [NoncompliantClass new];
        NoncompliantClass *cat2 = [NoncompliantClass new];
        NSArray *herdableCats = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cat1,cat2,nil];

        ArchiverDelegate *delegate = [ArchiverDelegate new];
        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
        NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
        [archiver setDelegate:delegate];
        [archiver encodeObject:herdableCats forKey:@"badKitties"];
        [archiver finishEncoding];
    }
}
```

This logs:

```
2012-09-18 05:24:02.091 TestSerialization[10808:303] Encoding __NSArrayI
2012-09-18 05:24:02.093 TestSerialization[10808:303] Encoding NoncompliantClass
2012-09-18 05:24:02.093 TestSerialization[10808:303] Substituting
2012-09-18 05:24:02.094 TestSerialization[10808:303] Encoding NoncompliantClass
2012-09-18 05:24:02.094 TestSerialization[10808:303] Substituting
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate feedback and this method seems to answer my question but I think this is too much. My second idea is just to store the properties into a NSDictionary object manually, and then have that serialized instead. Since this method also involves encoding each property manually, I will also have trouble encoding non-NSCoding compliant object again. (I'm trying to find an easy way that encodes the whole SKProduct to the deepest level)

Comment: The bigger question - one that I missed earlier - is how you are going to unarchive `SKProduct` regardless of the path you take to get there.  It appears all of its properties are read-only.  (Probably for good reason, if you think about it...)