# How to Persist Application State in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, persistent, nswindowrestoration

I need to store the state of application at application termination time, so that when user re-run app, App run from the state in which it was closed last time. It is some kind of restoring app but restore methods called when app close unexpectedly. But i need to restore app each time when it close unexpectedly of user close it manually.
I just need to store the App UI not the data of application.
Any idea would be helpful for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can persist the state in any of the available methods like:

**i. `NSUserDefaults`**

Example:

```
//saving
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"testBool"];
//retrieving
[defaults boolForKey:@"testBool"];
```

**ii. Serializing the  state object.**

- [iOS 4 iPhone Data Persistence using Archiving](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Data_Persistence_using_Archiving)
- [Correct way to save/serialize custom objects in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413851/correct-way-to-save-serialize-custom-objects-in-ios)

**iii. Saving as a plist file**

Example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *stateDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//set state
...

//saving
[stateDictionary writeToFile:<filePath> atomically:YES];

//retrieve
stateDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:<filePath>]
```

**iv. Using sqlite or Core-Data**

(Most probably not needed unless the
    state of your app is in some kind of a object relational model)

**UPDATE:**
For preserving the UI state of windows,
 Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html) and under the heading  **USER INTERFACE PRESERVATION**.

Comment: Can u explain how to use these to store the frame of controls which is added on NSWindow. and please don't tell to store frame of each controls, because i have many controls on window and storing each control frame is a very big task.

Comment: Unfortunately NSWindow is not directly serializable or writable to file. You can have either subclass NSWindow to override the encoding methods (See the link for list item ii) or you could check the link that I provided in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    //saveData
    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

If you want to save NSWindow position , you can use   `[window saveFrameUsingName:@"myWindow"];`
and use
`[window setFrameAutosaveName:@"myWindow"];` @ the app launch.

Comment: i know this method, it is called at the app termination time. My problem is, how to store app state (UI control's position).

Comment: strore UI control's position in NSUserDefaults

Comment: You can use saveFrameUsingName: to save NSWindow position  setFrameAutosaveName: